# What are police procedures in France when the victim is a traveler?

Tags: france, safety, health, security, officials

I have a friend who went to France a few days ago. Now I have received the following message from a friend of hers:

"Hello, I'm Amanda's friend (fictional name) and I received a call from where she is informing that she's at the hospital that she's injured at a hospital"

I asked for details…

"All I know is that she's physically injured, she also said you'd know what happened, they (the hospital staff) don't know what happened either"

And yes, I know what happened, but this is police matter (details removed)

Guy I suspect has already been arrested in my country and is sought by the police here, I want to find a way of informing the French police before he leaves the country.

I also don't know how to contact the French police or even find the hospital my friend is in, and I don't speak French.

I would also like to know what are the conditions in which the police may already be in the case.

Comment: What about contacting her embassy in France and ask for advice? For example, the UK government is providing a [brochure](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/rape-and-sexual-assault-abroad) on this topic.

Comment: I'll search for the contact

Comment: This is exactly the kind of serious issue that your country's consulate should be able to help with. Your consulate office in France will be able to speak French and interact with the police and hospitals there. It is especially important to get the consulate involved if this same man is already in trouble with the police in your home country.

Comment: We **truly hope you get help** with your serious situation, but this is not a forum that can help with this sort of police matter. The first thing to do is contact the police in your country, then the consulate or embassy of your country in France (probably in Paris). Hope it helps!

Comment: This question should be closed, because, it **does not help other people in the future** in serious situations if they see such questions and think anyone here can help them.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a scam to garner money from you ??  Such cases have happened in the past for British tourists travelling in South America/Africa.

Comment: @DumbCoder my first thought as well, but the mention of a person known by the recipient of the message to be liable to end up in such situations makes it more believable (though of course that "friend" may well be involved in the scam, only way to find out is to have a consular officer visit that hospital and check).

Comment: @JoeBlow: Feel free to flag it for closure (if you haven't already), but I think it's a perfectly legitimate question (if a bit overboard on specific details), and could very well be useful to future visitors. Your first comment would actually be an indication that we *can, indeed* provide useful information to this person.

Comment: This was useful already, I'm not a traveler so I wasn't ready to deal with this sort of thing. This is not scam, no money was asked, the message came from the victim's phone number and "you'd know what happened" refers to a personal conversation I had with the victim inside my car before she left

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first step you would take the email you received to the police and tell them your story.  If the police in your country are looking for someone and you provide them with a good reason to believe an absconded person is in France, they will know what to do.

There is a global computer network connecting police departments in participating countries; and if they think it's appropriate they will use it.  Others have mentioned contacting your consulate in France.  It's a good idea also, but note that the hospital would have notified either the police or consulate as a matter of procedure.

Comment: (+1) I am not entirely sure but my understanding is that hospitals in France don't notify the police without the victim's consent unless there is an immediate threat (i.e. if there is no further threat, they won't necessarily initiate action if the victim does not want it, as seems to be the case here).

Comment: @Relaxed maybe, but if the police initiate the contact because they have someone in custody and need to talk to her as a witness, the hospital has little recourse but to cooperate. And if this is played as an extradition request to the French police, that'd likely be the procedure.

Comment: @jwenting That's a completely different question and you seem to be mixing up different things in ways that don't fully make sense. An extradition request would imply a procedure (in some other country) that's much more advanced and would not involve the hospital or testimony in France. That's obviously not what the question nor my comment were about…

Comment: @Relaxed if the police in his country are looking for the man, and hear he's in France, they'll try to get him extradited, which would get the French police involved. It's the scenario Gayot hints at.

Comment: @jwenting Yes but involved into what? Presumably in seizing the perpetrator, in several months from now. Nothing to do with what the hospital might or might not do now or in taking witness testimony (that's not what extraditions are for…). Anyway, I was just commenting on the second paragraph and the other scenario, the hospital notifying the French police, which would then initiate its own investigation into the most recent crime.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out it **was** a scam to garner money from me, what I wasn't expecting though was that **my "friend" was the scammer**.

- She was shaving her hair to tell people she had cancer
- She was mutilating herself to say she was agressed
- She took some drug to make her breasts make milk so she could say she got pregnant from rape
- She had proper dressing to hide her hernia (http://pedroaraujo.site.med.br/fmfiles/index.asp/::XPR1XB::/H%E9rnia_incisional.jpg) so she could show it only when convenient to justify a story of aggresion
- And so on
- Her family also supports her with houses and people to support her lies, acting as a gang.
- She very seldonly asked for money, she just kept doing it until u decided yourself to help her paying the hipothetical lawer and medicine (where in my case was around a month).

Because I don't want to have my name against a gang that knows where I live, I tried to make an anonymous delation on the police, but they simply answered they can't do anything without someone signing the delation and even if I did, it's highly unlikely that she'll be arrested because this is a "low dangerousness crime" and they won't give me police protection either.

By the way, I live in Brazil.